# What is a referencing outlet?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I just recently upgraded my copy of Xcode 3 to Xcode 3.1, and I noticed something new in interface builder - the referencing outlet. Can anyone explain what referencing outlets are, and how they relate to mac development?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are outlets that are set to the object in question. For example, if you select an object that is a window's delegate, the window's `delegate` outlet will show as one of the object's referencing outlets. If it isn't the window's delegate, you can make it so by dragging from the “New Referencing Outlet” circle to the window, then clicking on the window's `delegate` outlet.

It's not a new kind of outlet; it's just viewing the same outlets from the perspective of the objects *in* the outlets instead of that of the objects owning the outlets.