# Referencing Outlet: example, functional meaning

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, iboutlet

I looked over the following threads:

1.[What's the difference between outlet and referencing outlet in a simple sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785735/whats-the-difference-between-outlet-and-referencing-outlet-in-a-simple-sentence)

2.[What is a referencing outlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633295/what-is-a-referencing-outlet)

But still have a big trouble understanding of why we need referencing outlet. Functionally, I mean. Could anyone give as detailed as possible example, explaining it to a beginner?

Right now I am going through Big Nerd Ranch textbook on iOS and they have in 10th chapter (about UINavigationController) a view that has three textfields. They make outlets in a controller and connect them to the textfields. But then happens what I can not get: they say to also connect these fields to the File Owner's delegate. Why do we need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of Chapter 10, you'll encounter a code like this

```
item.itemName = self.nameField.text;
item.serialNumber = self.nameField.text;
item.valueInDollars = [self.valueField.text intValue];
```

To put it in simpler terms, we need to connect these textFields to make a reference to these outlets.(nameField, serialNumberField, valueField) 
If we don't make a reference to these outlets, xCode would not be able to tell which text field the user is referring to when the user edits each text field.

As for why we connect text fields to the File Owner's delegate? We need to do this so that view controller can conform to a protocol  and then later call [self.view endEditing:YES] which tells xCode when the user is done editing text fields.
Look at the end of Chapter 7 "Delegates" and "Protocols" for more information.